# How was the deserted London scene in the movie '28 Days Later' filmed?

Tags: film-techniques, 28-days-later

I saw [this question about real-world filming locations](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/80662/) and it reminded me of an excellent zombie movie I saw few years ago called '28 Days Later'. In this movie, on waking up the protagonist finds himself roaming the streets of London alone. There is not even a single person.

The shots, streets, locations and backdrop looks so real I felt that it would be too much of a production cost to build entire locations (and buildings and the well-known monuments etc.) to shoot the deserted scenes.

[image]
[image]
[image]

My question is how were these scenes shot?

Comment: 4am on a summer Sunday, with some charming runners imploring motorists to wait a minute while they got their shot.

Comment: The direction of the light in the first and last still may be an indication of the season and time of day. I would guess that the clock face in at least the first still has been edited.

Comment: At this moment, the question has 28 upvotes. Appropriate.

Comment: This time of day is known as the "golden hour" (due to the light appearing gold, usually), and is used in many, many movies when necessary for deserted streets. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_hour_(photography)



http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GhostCity (short list of films included)

Comment: @sdenham the first picture is looking almost due West, so the shadows & clock could match if it wasn't high summer. The 3rd pic is looking North North West, so again, early morning could generate that highlight top left on the building. The sky would have to be tricked up later, sun would be too far camera right to really do that to the sky, & in fact I'm seeing a graduated filter on that shot, which could account for the colour-cast. [cont'd...]

Comment: [...cont'd] What appears to be light on the top of the building front right I can't explain, other than maybe they threw up some big 12k's to flatten the light in the foreground, or it was just cloudy enough to flatten it naturally. There's a bit of a halo around the posts in front of that building, so maybe there's some post-processing gone on in that area.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Normally, movie producers would obtain permits to shut down roads around city filming locations. However, this is not usually permitted in London (even huge productions like Bond get very limited privileges in London), unlike a lot of America cities. Although, it seems that the producers were able to get some road closures, but under very limited conditions.

To get around this, the empty London scenes were shot very early in the morning - sunrise in London is about 5am in the summer, and there is a long dusk before true sunrise which gives a decent amount of light. In fact, the dusk light (the golden light you see in some of the stills you posted) was probably used to provide an additional sense of eeriness to some scenes, along with some filtering/grading to reduce its effect in others.

> Before we started the main shoot we took a week in July, beginning each day at three or four every morning and would wait for the sun to come up
>
> We were able to shoot for an hour or so before the city got too busy for us to hold back the traffic. It was very exciting, and when you see the whole of Westminster Bridge and the embankment all closed for you, and the traffic stopped, and you can't hear anything, it was thrilling but strange as well.

[Source: *28 Days Later : About The Shoot*](http://cinema.com/articles/1468/28-days-later-about-the-shoot.phtml)

A lot of the scenes are filmed in the inner cities of Westminster and London (the City of London itself is a square mile in the middle of Greater London), and these are mostly commercial and government offices - not a lot of residential areas - so there was not a huge number of people waking up and heading to work.

However, even in the wee hours of the morning, Westminster and London and the surrounding areas are not completely empty. I think if you look carefully there is at least one brief shot of a moving bus in the distance. Mostly, the crew would reset and try for another shot if something like that happened.

I remember reading around the time of the movie coming out, that a bigger problem were drunken revellers spilling out of nearby bars and clubs - the production crew hired a number of attractive young women to distract and guide people around the shoot.

Comment: Your last paragraph isn't in the article.  Source?

Comment: I'm trying to remember the source - it was something I read around the time of the movie coming out. I might qualify it...

Comment: It might be worth adding that some films (not sure if it was used here) also digitally remove things like inconvenient vehicles or if there are power lines visible in a historical drama or similar.

Comment: Good answer, and I believe this is also in the IMDB trivia; which OP should have checked first.

Comment: @TimB they certainly do now - but I don't think this was used for the film in question

Comment: @sirjonsnow although the interview is not in imdb - I'm dubious about using imdb as a source

Comment: @Wildcard - no source except it's actually a common problem. Some London clubs don't close until 4 or 5.. so crews often have to persuade drunks that no, they don't really need any more extras right now, thank you very much ;-)

Comment: btw, they managed to close Whitehall & Northumberland Place for half a day each for Skyfall - again, roads that aren't so busy on Sunday. The Mall is also a favourite for Sunday filming. They usually leave passage on one side for pedestrians, between takes, but traffic is re-routed for the duration.

Comment: @Tetsujin Bond is a bit of a national treasure and has such larger budget, so can get away with a lot more than smaller productions

Comment: @Wildcard It's in the [trivia section on IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0289043/trivia?item=tr0755204): "*For the London scenes, police would close the roads at 4am, and filming would begin immediately. After 1 hour, the police would reopen the roads. The producers correctly predicted that asking drivers (including clubbers headed home) to either wait for up to an hour or find another route might make some of them angry. They got several extremely attractive young women (including Danny Boyle's daughter) to make the necessary requests, and the drivers responded quite amicably to them.*"

Comment: I would imagine that there is a digital video equivalent of setting up a tripod, taking a series of photos, taking the statistical median from multiple photos - this would remove any people/cars that have "moved" during the scene - then the relevant parties can be added back (possibly from being filmed elsewhere like with a greenscreen) or selectively not removed - possibly multiple tripods, stitching the image together into a large one, and then panning as needed for moving with the video

Comment: @user2813274 - there is an equivalent... but runners are cheap... & ultimately disposable ;-)

Comment: Thank you for this @HorusKol ! they were filmed in important places and i didn't know if they would even be permitted to stop the traffic for the shoot. I did check imdb but I don't think I checked the trivia section.

Comment: A bit more on that interview and the angry young men:

_‘Hey, hello. Good morning. We’re making a movie here. Do you mind waiting for two minutes?’ ‘No problem, darling. I’ll wait here. What’s your name?’ And so every day we hired more and more of these girls to block the traffic. And there’s not a moment of CG in it, where we took out vehicles or anything like that.”_

https://editorial.rottentomatoes.com/article/most-memorable-movie-moments-28-days-later-hello/

Answer (score 12):

An addendum to HorusKol's answer, rather than one that would stand alone...

The bridges in London are hard to close for any length of time - as Paul D. Waite mentioned in his comment, you get lots of runners to stand in the way of people, pleading/cajoling them not to walk across the location whilst the cameras are actually rolling.

The rest of the time, the roads are open.
Depending on how long it takes, the shout will go up to "Lock off" & everybody holds their particular road until cut. Then the traffic flows again until the next take.

On the other hand, the 3rd picture is of Waterloo Place [Just North of the Mall, central London.
The Southern end of the road is an easy 'impressive-looking' road to close off for a whole Sunday, because it doesn't really go anywhere & it's simple to drive round if you really have to be somewhere obstructed by the filming.

[Link to Google Streets](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/@51.5066575,-0.1318977,3a,75y,325.49h,76.12t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s5XCvsYkC1MMZpq7Sq7eGDg!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) - From approximately where that shot was done -  currently showing a view from March 2017... with a unit base already taking up the street. It's used as a film base very frequently [though not when they need to shoot there, of course, then they'll use the adjacent Carlton House Terrace.]

Comment: Thank You, precisely my doubt - its the london bridge ! i didn't expect that the traffic could be shut down for even a while.. which is why i wondered